# Logarithm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw the following statement in a paper:

"When $A$ and $B$ are positive invertible, one can define $\log AB$ by analytical
functional calculus or by power series and get the equality 
$$\text{Tr} \left(A\log A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\right)=\text{Tr}\left(A\log AB\right)$$
because $\text{Tr} A(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^n = \text{Tr}A(AB)^n$ for $n\geq 1$."

Is this statement correct? Apparently the definition of matrix logarithm is based on the exponential of a matrix, and I couldn't find a power series to define matrix logarithm.

There is a series for matrix logarithm in this post: [Existence of logarithm of non-singular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481459/existence-of-logarithm-of-non-singular-matrix), but it has an extra unit matrix inside the logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, so is $C = A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$.  Letting $c$ be the average of the greatest and least eigenvalues of $C$, we find that the spectral radius of $C - c I$ is less than $c$.  Thus

$$\log(C) = \log(c I + (C - cI)) = \log(c) + \log(I + (C/c - I))$$

has a convergent series

$$\log(C) = \log(c) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (C/c - I)^n $$

Now $C/c - I = A^{1/2} (B/c - A^{-1}) A^{1/2}$ has the same eigenvalues as 
$ A (B/c - A^{-1}) = A B/c - I$, and thus we have the converging series

$$\log(AB) = \log(cI + AB-cI) = \log(c) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (AB/c - I)^n $$